# Proof for pumping lemma for new kind of CFL

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar, pumping-lemma

I have a context-free grammar $(V,\Sigma,R,S)$ that is defined by the condition that every production in $R$ has to be on one of the following two forms:

$A\to uBv$ where $A,B\in V$ and $u,v\in\Sigma^*$

and

$A\to u$ where $A\in V$ and $u\in\Sigma^*$

The pumping lemma for languages that are produced by this grammar goes much like the pumping lemma for CFL, but the third condition is a little bit different. In the pumping lemma for CFL, the condition states that $|vxy|\leq p$, but for this new language, the condition is as follows:

$|uv|\leq p$ and $|yz|\leq p$

Can I prove the pumping lemma for this language in a similar way to the proof for pumping lemma for CFL?

Comment: Grammars of this form are called [*linear grammars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar) and they are well more than half a century past being "new". (See, for example, this [famous paper by Sheila Greibach, written in 1966](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/321356.321365).)

Comment: I see. We weren't given a name for the grammar. Probably so that we couldn't look it up online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same basic idea to prove the pumping lemma for this kind of grammar. In some ways it’s easier, since the derivation tree is simpler: it has a single ‘spine’ of non-terminal symbols with terminal symbols coming off the spine on each side. The calculation of $p$ is perhaps the biggest difference: you’ll have to take into account both $|V|$ and the maximum lengths of $u$ and $v$ in productions of the type $A\to uBv$. It would be a little easier if you first proved that such a grammar can be converted to one in which every production is either of the form $A\to u$ with $A\in V$ and $u\in\Sigma^*$ or of the form $A\to \sigma B\tau$ with $A,B\in V$ and $\sigma,\tau\in\Sigma$.